# macOS Google update fails with “Agent is running as user id 502, which is not the console user. Bailing”

Tags: macos, software-update

I am using an iMac with High Sierra (10.13.2). There are some problems with it running slowly and as part of the investigation have looked at the system.log file.

Google Software Update seems to be finding an error every time it runs, which is:

> “Agent is running as user id 502, which is not the console user. Bailing.”

Does anyone have any insights into what is going on?

Comment: Check if 502 is an admin account, & if it's your account. First account should always be 501. System prefs/Users & groups [unlock] right click an account to get the advanced options. Don't change anything unless you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the same error when I manually tried to update Chrome because it kept saying Chrome is outdated.

I don't know why it happened or what the root cause is but the problem has gone when I [uninstalled](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95319) and reinstalled Chrome.